# Pass JVM arguments in Databricks Jobs API

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, jvm-arguments

I want to pass JVM arguments to a REST request using Jobs API in Databricks. Is it possible to do it? Any hints would help.

Something like -Dconfig-file=app.conf to the spark job.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "**spark_conf**" attribute in the REST API Jobs .

**spark_conf:** An object containing a set of optional, user-specified Spark configuration key-value pairs. You can also pass in a string of extra JVM options to the driver and the executors via spark.driver.extraJavaOptions and spark.executor.extraJavaOptions respectively.

**Example:** Spark confs: {"spark.speculation": true, "spark.streaming.ui.retainedBatches": 5} or {"spark.driver.extraJavaOptions": "-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails"}

**How to use in Jobs API:** To create a cluster enabled for table access control, specify the following spark_conf property in your request body:

```
curl -X POST https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/clusters/create -d'
{
  "cluster_name": "my-cluster",
  "spark_version": "5.2.x-scala2.11",
  "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
  "spark_conf": {
    "spark.databricks.acl.dfAclsEnabled":true,
    "spark.databricks.repl.allowedLanguages": "python,sql"
  },
  "num_workers": 1,
  "custom_tags":{
     "costcenter":"Tags",
     "applicationname":"Tags1"
  }
}'
```

For more details, refer "[API examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/examples#--jobs-api-examples)" and "[How to add spark configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58688544/azure-databricks-how-to-add-spark-configuration-in-databricks-cluster)".